# Issues-Only Access Permissions GitHub

Tags: github

I am trying to follow the [Issues-Only Access Permissions](https://help.github.com/articles/issues-only-access-permissions) help information at GitHub, but I fail to understand how the issues propagate from the Issues-Only repository to the private repository.

Can someone please clarify in more detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [use commit messages to close issues across repositories](https://github.com/blog/1439-closing-issues-across-repositories).

For instance, if you have two repositories, `tyst/project` and `tyst/project-issues` (with the former hosting the private code), you could close issues in the latter by using commit messages (like `fixes tyst/project-issues#14`) so long as the person making the commit has write permissions to both repositories.